# RDF for a Freebase topic

Tags: rdf, freebase

I am using the python library `rdflib` to query Freebase for topics.

I found that the data returned by Freebase for topics are not complete. For instance, when I query:

`http://rdf.freebase.com/rdf/en.barack_obama`

The result does not contain data about *`place_of_birth`* although I can verify that the data exists when I use MQL to query for that property.

My question is: **Can I rely on a query to the RDF service to return all the rdf triples for a given topic?**

If not, is there a way to ensure I get all the triples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer is no. Certain topics link to thousands of other topics in Freebase and our APIs would timeout if we didn't impose a limit on the number of triples returned. We're going to be releasing a complete RDF dump of Freebase in the near future. That will be the best way to get all the RDF data.

Comment: Take this as an authoritative answer: Shawn works @ Google / Freebase!
Thanks, Shawn, for all that is you do on fb.

Comment: Thank you Shawn! Do you have an idea when the RDF dump will be available? In the meantime, would you recommend using MQL or the Topic API instead? Thanks.